# Symfony2 form choice expended default select

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm doing a filter form in symfony2
and I try to preselect some filds.

I got two choices:

```
$formBuilder->add('first', 'choice',
    array('choices' => $choiceFirst,
    'expanded' => false,
     'multiple' => true,
     'data' => explode(' ', $this->getRequest()->get('first'))
));
$formBuilder->add('second', 'choice',
    array('choices' => $choiceSecond,
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'data' => explode(' ', $this->getRequest()->get('second'))));
```

For the first choice which is not expanded the datas pass by url are preselect.
But not for the second which is expanded.

There is any ways to preselect checkboxs from a field choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You must provide an array of selected values as data for a multiple choice field.</strike>

edit: irrelevant answer, my mistake

Try to provide a key => boolean array as the checked state depends on a boolean value.

I think you only have to put checked value in your array, so those one that are true ;)

Comment: It's what I do. I give both an array and the data seem to be good because if I set expanded: false the datas are selected in the list.
My problem is that when the field is expanded the datas are not selected

Comment: Sorry, i made a confusion between expanded and multiple. I delete my answer that is irrelevant...

Comment: No it was because the get value is a string and my checkbox values are int.
So my previous data look like: array(707 => '707)
And now: array(707 => 707)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution i find for this issue is to simply set the default value to your object before generate the form.

Like : `$myEntity->setMyfieldchoice(1);`

This way symfony will understand this value is the default value (worked for my on a select field).

Hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$formBuilder->add('first', 'choice',
   array('choices' => array('0' => 'first option', '1' => 'second option'),
   'expanded' => false,
   'multiple' => true,
   'data' => explode(' ', $this->getRequest()->get('first'))
));
```

And view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.first.0) }}
{{ form_widget(form.first.1) }}
```

For me works.